# How can I create a dataframe combining all values of different variables (R)?

Tags: r, loops

I would like to create a dataframe with id, year and month columns with all combinations of the values below.

```
id <- c(1002,463,546,9787,849,34)
years <- 2000:2009
months <- 1:12
```

In this simple example, the total number of rows of the dataframe I am looking to get should have `6*10*12` rows. Each one of the `6` ids should show up in `10*12` rows, each one referring to a given year-month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `expand.grid`

```
expand.grid(id,years,months)
```

Comment: Also `expand_grid(id, years, months)`